# Loopback - Calling getCurrentContext inside an operation hook gives incorrect accessToken

Tags: strongloop, loopback

I am running into what looks like a bug in how loopback handles context, specifically when trying to get the context from within an operation hook.

We have code which inside the before save operation hook gets the context via getCurrentContext() and gets the access token off of that.

What we are finding is that the access token is incorrect - often returning access tokens for other logged in users.

Our steps to reproduce are:

1. Log in as user A
2. Perform action which hits after save hook on a
   model, and inside that after save log the access token on the
   context
3. Log out, log in as user B
4. Perform same action and record
   access token.  Notice that token is the same as token for user A

Curious if anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a (known) bug in LoopBack, see the existing two issues:

- [getCurrentContext.get() sometimes returns other request/user's information](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/2397)
- [context.get('currentUser'); is not accessible from User.observe hook](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/2004)

My advice is to join the discussion in one of those GitHub issues.

Comment: I actually posted that first issue. :)  BTW on investigating this more what I'm finding is that the context stack (the _set variable inside the CLS component) changes if you call from within a promise.  So the issue is not actually related to the operation hooks from what I can tell but rather the fact that we are calling a .create from within a promise chain which then invokes the hook.

Comment: I am afraid the module continuation-local-storage (which we use to implement getCurrentContext) is buggy, your use case would be an example of a situation not supported by the module. There isn't much we can do about it in LoopBack, in fact we are considering to deprecate getCurrentContext() entirely.